# How to install 12.04 on Samsung Series 5 Ultrabook?

Tags: 12.04, live-usb, samsung

A few days ago, I bought this laptop, and now I want to change its OS (Windows 7) to Ubuntu but failed.

I burn it to a USB stick, set BIOS to startup from USB and it worked. I followed the install steps to install Ubuntu, it was a success. But when I restart the computer after installation, it's not working, it'll be continual reboot at start up until I shutdown or let it start up from USB stick.

Can anybody to tell me this is why? Please help me to resolve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be because you installed GRUB on a partition. To resolve this:

- Boot from the Live USB.
- Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
- Run the following commands:

  ```
  sudo grub-install /dev/sda
  sudo update-grub
  ```

  Here, `/dev/sda` is the name of the harddrive. To check the name of the harddrive, run `sudo fdisk -l`.

[image]

In the screenshot, the devices `/dev/sda1`, etc are the partitions, whereas `/dev/sda` is the harddrive.